# Non linear regression: $y = f(x_1) + g(x_2 - h(x_1))$

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression

Suppose my dependent variable $y$ is generated from continuous variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ by the model,

$$y = C + f(x_1) + g(x_2 - h(x_1)) + \text{noise},$$

where $f$, $g$, $h$ are smooth nice functions. How can I model or recover these functions given the observed data?  I really don't want to specify the functional form of $f$, $g$, $h$, and would like to use a spline to approximate them.  An example of a real world scenario where this form is useful may be where $h(x_1) = \mathbb{E}[X_2|x_1]$.  (Note that if $g$ is linear, then $y = C + (f+gh)(x_1) + g(x_2) + \text{noise}$, which is easy to model, but it is still hard to recover the functions.)

The final example `mgcv` fit below fits the data very well, but it's not very clear why it does well, nor can I recover $f$, $g$, $h$.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

f <- function(x) 15*x^1.7
g <- function(x) 3*x^3
h <- function(x) 100-5*x^0.5
C <- 40
sigma <- 2

# y = C + f(x1) + g(x2 - h(x1))

simulation <- crossing(observed_x1 = seq(1, 10), latent_x2_deviation = seq(-5, 5)) %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% # pretend continous data
  mutate(latent_x2_expected = h(observed_x1)) %>%
  mutate(observed_x2 = latent_x2_expected + latent_x2_deviation) %>%
  mutate(y_clean = C + f(observed_x1) + g(observed_x2 - h(observed_x1))) %>%
  mutate(y_noisy = y_clean + stats::rnorm(n(), 0, sigma))

plot_ly(simulation) %>%
  add_markers(x = ~observed_x1, y = ~observed_x2, z = ~y_clean)

mgcv::gam(y_noisy ~ s(observed_x1) + s(observed_x2), data = simulation) %>%
  summary()

mgcv::gam(y_noisy ~ s(observed_x1) + s(observed_x2) + ti(observed_x1, observed_x2), 
  data = simulation) %>%
  summary()
```

Comment: In the real world scenario that you give $h$ is identified outside of your regression  model. If this is the setting you have in mind then you should focus on it (and maybe edit you question).

Comment: Are your data obtained on a regular grid of $(x_1,x_2)$ values or on irregularly situated values?

Comment: I would be interested in finding h together with g and f, without resorting to finding it outside the regression, as I can only do that for a very limited set of possible h's. And the data wouldn't be on a regular grid, it'll be continuous.